# <button> não funciona no Firefox dentro de um tema Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button

Estou criando um botão dentro de um tema Wordpress, porém o mesmo não funciona no Firefox, já no Chrome e IE funciona sem problema algum.

Meu botão:

```
<button class="faleconosco"><a class="texto_faleconosco" href="https://www.google.com.br">GOOGLE</a></button>
```

Comment: Tem um erro gerado no console do Firefox?

Comment: Tentei olhar no console e não apresenta nenhum erro ao clicar no botão.

Ao carregar a página é apresentado um erro de JS, veja:

String vazia passada para getElementById(). jquery.js:2:0

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu entender, um `<button>` é rendarizado e aje bem diferente do que um `<a>`, sendo esse um link. Parece que o IE e Chrome estão interpretando seu HTML de um modo que *acaba dando* o resultado desejada. Óbviamente o Firefox não interpreta da mesma maneira.

Se quer um link que tem a aparência de um `<button>` no browser, é melhor nem usar o `<button>`, e simplesmente usar um CSS para mudar a aparência do `<a>`. Algo assim:

#### HTML

```
<a class="button" href="https://www.google.com.br">GOOGLE</a>
```

#### CSS

```
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}
```

<sub><sup>Inspirado [dessa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906586/1245766)</sup></sub>

Comment: Se por acaso eu trocar <button> por uma <div> funciona belezinha, porém não quero modificar a organização do tema.

O tema inteiro usa o <button>.

Comment: Quer dizer que todos os `<button>`s do site não funciona em Firefox? Ou apenas esse que está modificando?

Comment: Apenas esse modificado que não funciona.

Comment: A próxima pergunta seria: é mais importante ter a *aparência* de um botão, ou *ser* um `<button>`?

Comment: Sim, é o botão do bootstrap, porém eu acrescentei algumas formatações em CSS.

Comment: Entendi. Se for bootstrap mesmo, é simplesmente colocar um `class="btn"` no `<a>` que vai estilar igual um botão

Comment: Olha neste link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772520/button-link-doesnt-work-in-firefox-ie